# Python: Tkinter :Dynamically Create Label

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create Label Dynamically , I am getting invalid Syntax. Can you please help me what i am missing or any alternative

```
      crsr = cnxn.execute(query)
        row_num=2
        column_num=0
        Variable_Number=1
        for row in crsr.fetchall():

            test='Column_Label'+str(Variable_Number)+' = tk.Label(frame,text="'+row[0]+'")'



#proper Indentation availabe in code        test1='Column_Label'+str(Variable_Number)+'.grid(row='+str(row_num)+',column='+str(column_num)+')'
            eval(test+';'+test1)
    #        eval(test1)
            row_num+=1
            column_num+=1
        root.update_idletasks()
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? using `exec` or `eval` to execute code is almost never the correct solution. Are you open to better ways to do this?

Comment: yes, i need a better solution and i am dying to contact since ages.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `exec`. If you want to associate a computed name with a widget in a loop, use a dictionary:

```
labels = {}
varnum = 0
for row in crsr.fetchall():
    name=f"label#{varnum}"
    labels[name] = tk.Label(frame, text=str(row[0]))
    labels[name].grid(row=row_num, column=column_num
    varnum += 1
    row_num+=1
    column_num+=1
```

If you don't really care what the name is, you can store the widgets in a list rather than a dictionary, and then reference them using an integer index (eg: `labels[0]`, `labels[1]`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Use exec() instead eval()

eval will evaluate a expression, not run it like you want.
Think of eval like the argument of a if statement.

Comment: They shouldn't use `exec` or `eval` - there are better ways.