# Create label and entry using Looping Method

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

i have an assignment creating label and entry using loops instead of typical method. my question is how can i change the value of **labels** against the table rows in my database.

example table rows:

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
win = tk.Tk()
win.title('LOOP')

labels = ['First Name : ' , 'Family Name :', 'Gender : ', 'Course : ', 'Section : ', 'Prof : ', 'School']



for i in range(len(labels)):
    cur_label = 'label' + str(i) 
    cur_label = ttk.Label(win, text = labels[i], font=("", 20,""))
    cur_label.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

name_var = tk.StringVar() 
user_info = {
    'Fname': tk.StringVar(),
    'FName': tk.StringVar(),
    'Gender': tk.StringVar(),
    'Course': tk.StringVar(),
    'Section': tk.StringVar(),
    'Prof': tk.StringVar(),
    'School' : tk.StringVar()
}
counter=0
for i in user_info:
    cur_entrybox = 'entry' + i
    cur_entrybox = ttk.Entry(win, width=16, textvariable=user_info[i], font=("", 20,""))
    cur_entrybox.grid(column=1, row=counter)
    counter += 1 


submit_btn = ttk.Button(win, text='Submit')
submit_btn.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)



win.mainloop()
```

thank you for your support

Comment: Just a heads up. This line `cur_entrybox = 'entry' + i` is doing nothing. The line after it, you're overwriting the string with an object.

Comment: @Axe319 thanks for your suggestion well noted, however do you have idea how to change **labels value ** to table row in mysql.

Comment: Have you tried to implement mysql? I don't see any database queries in your code. If so, what specific problems are you having with it?

Comment: I don't have idea sir the right query to get the table rows of my database.

Comment: Save the labels and entries to a list or dictionary. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60242182/7432 for an example.

Comment: any other answer